# Get the String with the most occurances in a column

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a `SQLite` `database` in an `Android` app that has a `column` named "locations".

**Example**

```
 Locations

 Home
 Home
 Home
 School
 Work
```

I'd like to run a `query` that returns the `String` `Home` because that is the `String` that occurs most frequently in this column. I've seen some similar posts but nothing using `SQLite` for an `Android` app.

***Note***
I'm looking for the least amount of code possible.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use answer by Dave but append limit 1 to the end of the query. also locations and not location as in the query.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of the "limit 1" when I was trying it.  I edited my answer (including the typo on the column/field name).

Comment: @IrishWhiskey I made a comment on Dave answer. Can you change the value for the locations in the first row. Or add more rows so that School or Work has more occurrances.

Comment: Never mind but if your locations column allows null then you should change to the comment I made below.

Comment: Never mind the whole thing, I am not thinking today. Your locations column should not allow null though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What types of similar things did you find?  You didn't say if you were using helpers or if you are trying this with straight/raw SQL queries.  The query I would try is

I would try:

```
select locations, count(*) as times from table group by locations order by times desc limit 1;
```

Then just grab the first one.

Comment: I am trying to use `rawQuery` to get the information. Then I will store it in a string to use in a message later. I will try this in 30 minutes when I resume coding, thank you for the answer. I will be appending `limit 1` to the end like Hoan suggested.

Comment: Answer edited to include the 'limit 1'. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I think about it, I don't think the query is right. Since count(*) return the numbers of row in the table. I think the answer is only right because the first row in locations has value Home. That is this query just return the first row.

Comment: Count(*) returns the number of rows after the match. By itself, it will count the number of rows; in this case it should return the locations column, group them, and count the rows in each group displaying them in descending order by the number of times each location is in the group. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: I forgot about group by but count(*) will count null. So it is better to have count(locations). Please edit your answer, also the location in group by should also has an s.